# twilio how pick a call from queue with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

Am creating a call queuing system with twiml everything is working like i can receive calls and enqueue calls but i can't pick a call from queue, i wrote this code but it is not working

This is my twiml when there is an incoming call:

I receive the first call the other following calls get queued but now after the first call ended i can't pick the queued calls. and when i hung up it put the first caller in a queue.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Please wait and one of our agents will be with you shortly.</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Client>joey</Client>
        <Parameter name="name" value="'.$name.'" />
        <Parameter name="email" value="'.$email.'" />
    </Dial>
    <Say>Our agents are still busy please hold.</Say>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="waiting.php">Support</Enqueue>
</Response>';

echo $message;
```

So to pick a call from queue i found this Twilio PHP code:

```
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

$support = $_REQUEST['To'];

$response = new VoiceResponse();
$response->say("You will now be connected to the first caller in the queue.");
$dial = $response->dial('');
$dial->queue($support, ['url' => 'about_to_connect.php']);

echo $response;
```

With this JavaSCript code

```
 queueButton.click(function() {
        Twilio.Device.connect({
            To: 'Support'
        });
    });
```

here i wanted to follow this answer [Twilio connecting an agent to a call in a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565109/twilio-connecting-an-agent-to-a-call-in-a-queue)

but when i click a button to pick a call nothing happens instead i get this js error

```
twilio.js:7100 Received an error from the gateway: {code: 31002, connection: Connection, message: "Connection Declined", twilioError: Error

code: 31005
description: "Connection error"
explanation: "A connection error occurred during the call"
```

All in all i just need a solution on how to connect an agent to a queue,
like see how many calls are in the queue and be able to pick them from queue

Please help

Thank in advanced

Comment: I figured out how to call queue by creating a twiml app and it worked but now i want a way to click a button on the agent side to call the queue. is it possible to get queueSize with twilio js or client.js, and if i enqueue the first call and the following calls can i still pass parameters like this: ```<Parameter name="name" value="'.$name.'" />
        <Parameter name="email" value="'.$email.'" />```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

So to call in to a queue i needed a second number that i can call the queue with, but i don't have a second number so since i have input.php file for the twiml Gather, i made an if statement checking whether the user calling is an agent or just a custome, if it is an agent i dial a queue

```
if($_POST['user_type'] == 'agent'){
  <Response>
    <Dial>
        <Queue url="about_to_connect.xml">my_queue_name</Queue>
    </Dial>
</Response>
}else{
  //My Gather here
}
```

to be able to check if the user is an agent or a customer, when i call the queue i pass a custom variable called user_type:

```
let connection = Twilio.Device.connect({
  "user_type": "agent"
});
```

so i was able to call my queues.
And that was when i realized twiml is awesome and its job is to control calls.

i recommend you buy a second number to avoid slowing down your calls.

Thanks